# webView does not load the page

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I FOUND THE PROBLEM... I found that the value of berria1 have "\n    " at the end of the url. where he not get this but that's the problem.

I pass very curious thing and which do not find any explanation.

The fact is that in the application, I'm parsing some news and save these in `CoreData`, then show a list of news in a `UITableView` and if I click on one of them brings me to a `UIWebView` in which position the link with the full story. Now comes the weird ...

If I pass to `NSURL` the variable which I recovery of `CoreData` which contains the Web address, do not load,  if I pass the same direction to a `NSString` and this `NSString` to `UIWebView`, the `UIWebView` load this normally. The following is my code.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.webView.delegate = self;

    NSString *berria1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
    berria1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.abisua.noticia];

    NSString *berria2 = @"http://www.vitoria-gasteiz.org/we001/was/we001Action.do?idioma=eu&aplicacion=wb021&tabla=contenido&uid=u_47906a5c_14eabe80aeb__7fe9";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:berria1];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

    NSLog(@"El contenido de la noticia 1 es %@", berria1);
    NSLog(@"El contenido de la noticia 2 es %@", berria2);

}
```

With the `NSLog` I see that the values of the variables are the same as you see in the picture below.

[The value of the two variables in the NSLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeCoy.png)

[Image - Debug window - URL is nil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFxr6.png)

That could be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: where is your code part of load request to the web view

Comment: show me the load request to the web view

Comment: Set NSAppTransportSecurity  key to NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in info.plist

Comment: NSAppTransportSecurity is changed

Comment: I add a new image, berria1 has a value, but when I pass berria1 to URL, URL is nil.

Comment: Please answer the answer in the answer segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found and fixed the problem.

The problem was that the variable received whith `Core Data` and pass to `NSString`, I do not know how, but the link have added this characters at the end of `URL` "\n "

`Berria1` variable value in debug area was:

```
berria1 __NSCFString *  @"http://www.vitoria-gasteiz.org/we001/was/we001Action.do?idioma=eu&aplicacion=wb021&tabla=contenido&uid=u_47906a5c_14eabe80aeb__7fe9\n      "  0x0000000126d9e6c0
```

Then when I passed this value to `NSURL` and this found these characters, `NSURL` value pass to nil.

Then I solved this, passing this `NSString` to a `NSMutableString` and erasing these characters before pass to `NSURL` with this code:

```
NSString *berria1 = self.abisua.noticia;

NSMutableString * miCadena = [NSMutableString stringWithString: berria1];
[miCadena deleteCharactersInRange: [miCadena rangeOfString: @"\n      "]];
```

Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

Its not berria1 which holds the URL its berria2.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:berria2];
```

Here you go give it a try the site is pretty slow so it takes a time to load

```
NSString *berria2 = @"http://www.vitoria-gasteiz.org/we001/was/we001Action.do?%20%20%20%20idioma=eu&aplicacion=wb021&tabla=contenido&uid=u_47906a5c_14eabe80aeb__7fe9";

NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:berria2];

NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];

[self.webView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

Comment: Rahul, berria1 and berria2 have the same URL, I pass the url to berria1 recovering this in core data. if you see the picture, two variables have the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I didn't see any code how you load the request to webview. But I added the code with that part. Replace it with your webview.

```
NSString *myurlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.abisua.noticia];
NSString *cleanedUrl = [myurlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:cleanedUrl];
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];

UIWebView *mywebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[mywebview loadRequest:myRequest];
```

Comment: updated the answer.if this also not works, put your code where you load the request to your webview

Answer (score 0):

hi am new to iOS developer,i have seen your code in that your adding second string to url why still understand just try adding 2nd string

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:berria2];
```

Comment: I have been trying to pass first berria1 and second berria2 with the same url and one works well an the other no with the same url.

Comment: I found that the value of one berria have "\ n" at the end of the url. where he not get this but that's the problem

Comment: hi Aitor Urania Barandika  i am added code to custom framework ,how to build the frame work please give procedure steps

Comment: i getting  this error Lipo Error!! can't open input file in universal schema remaining (.app )schemas  are builded successful  i don't no why i am getting that error please help me

Comment: hi Nagendar, I do not understand well, but the problem is solved. I've put a little below.

Comment: i got an error above mentioned give me any suggestions

Comment: hello guys any one know about tesseract ocr , i have doubt in that this ocr output is giving extra numbers also . i am given input image with number 62 its showing output like 152  please give suggestions     Thank you all